# Merging two arrays without changing key values by keeping array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have tree arrays in php as shown in the code

```
<?php
//old array
$oldArray = array(0 => 11, 1 => 18, 2 => 29, 3 => 35, 4 => 40);

// held values
$hold = array( 1 => 18, 3 => 35);

// new random generated array

$newValues = array( 0 => 27, 1 => 31, 2 => 38);


//I need keep keys (order, index) of $hold values

newArrayMergedPushed = array(0 => 27, 1 => 18, 2 => 31, 3 => 35, 4 => 38);
?>
```

I need keep order of $hold array in same order,index like in $oldArray.
What function can I use in php so that the following output is obtained without changing key values?

Comment: key values are changing. Where does `2 => 31` come from?

Comment: I need $hold + $newValues = $newArrayMergedPushed in order like above.

Comment: I don't get the order. I don't get the logic in `$newArrayMergedPushed`. Why value 31 has the index 2? Why not 1? How did you choose? Giving a solution for this case in particular is easy. But if we don't get the logic, there are chances this solution won't work in another case. :)

Comment: `$newVAlues[2] = 38` and `$hold[2]` is not set.  So how does adding those together give you `31`?  Also, other than defining what you want done, what have you tried.  Last, don't forget the `$` in front of `newArrayMergedPushed`.

Comment: Ok,from $oldArray I keeping 18 and 35, and generate tree new values.I need keep 18 and 35 in same order like in $oldArray after merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing what you want to do correctly, it's probably better to operate directly on the array you want to change rather than creating a range first and then trying to mix them back in.

Hold only the indexes that you want to keep in a lookup table, then loop over the table and replace any key=>values that aren't held.

```
$oldArray = array(0 => 11, 1 => 18, 2 => 29, 3 => 35, 4 => 40);
$hold = array( 1 => true, 3 => true);
for( $i = 0; $i < count($oldArray); $i ++ ) {
  if( !isset( $hold[$i] ) ) {
    $oldArray[$i] = mt_rand(0,100); // or whatever you do to generate random numbers
  }
}
```

That way you won't have to do any merging at all.

Comment: New values came from: array_rand($indexes, 3);